# How to design the appearance of text in mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a question and answer stored in the object. The request comes in the form of a question and I would like to get an attractive appearance of the text for the answer. For example, bold key words, or underlined words.
Is it possible to store such text in the mongo database, or will I have to create a java class that will process all keywords and edit them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should process the data in class as required.
Database responsibility is to keep the data not the fancy stuff